# How to map a property of type Dictionary<string, MyDto> using fluent mapping

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a dictionary which I want to map using fluent mapping, and for some properties of MyDto class, I need to add normalizer.

```
new CreateIndexDescriptor("indexName")
.Mappings(ms => ms.Map<Entity>(e => new PutMappingDescriptor<Entity>()
 .AutoMap()
 .Properties(o => o.Object<IDictionary<string, MyDto>>(
  m => m.AutoMap().Name(f => f.SomeProperty))
```

my class definitions:

```
class MyEntity {
...
Dictionary<string, MyDto> SomeProperty {get;set;}
...
}
class MyDto {
...
string Name {get;set;}
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to add this as an explicit mapping, but it is through a dynamic template.

Let's look at why it's not possible through explicit mapping. Consider how `Dictionary<string, MyDto> SomeProperty` will serialize to JSON. For example

```
client.IndexDocument(new MyEntity 
{
    SomeProperty = new Dictionary<string, UserQuery.MyDto>
    {
        { "field_1", new MyDto { Name = "foo" } },
        { "field_2", new MyDto { Name = "bar" } }
    }
});
```

by default will serialize as

```
{
  "someProperty": {
    "field_1": {
      "name": "foo"
    },
    "field_2": {
      "name": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

If we wanted to apply an explicit mapping to `MyDto.Name`, we would need to know at the point of mapping, all of the dictionary keys that will be used.

You can however, [configure a dynamic template that will map any `MyDto.Name` as a `keyword` type, using `path_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch)

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "my_index";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(1)
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MyEntity>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .DynamicTemplates(dt => dt
                    .DynamicTemplate("MyDto", dtd => dtd
                        .PathMatch("someProperty.*.name")
                        .Mapping(dm => dm
                            .Keyword(k => k)
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Object<Dictionary<string, MyDto>>(o => o
                        .Name(n => n.SomeProperty)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var indexResponse = client.Index(new MyEntity 
    {
        SomeProperty = new Dictionary<string, UserQuery.MyDto>
        {
            { "field_1", new MyDto { Name = "foo" } },
            { "field_2", new MyDto { Name = "bar" } }
        }
    }, i => i.Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor));

    var mappingResponse = client.GetMapping<MyEntity>();
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public Dictionary<string, MyDto> SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping response confirms that `someProperty.field_1.name` and `someProperty.field_2.name` are mapped as `keyword`

```
{
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "myentity" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [
          {
            "MyDto" : {
              "path_match" : "someProperty.*.name",
              "mapping" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties" : {
          "someProperty" : {
            "properties" : {
              "field_1" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "field_2" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### An aside on mapping explosion

You may want to consider adding a property to `MyDto` to hold the dictionary key, and use a `List<MyDto>` or similar collection [mapped as a `nested` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html), rather than `Dictionary<string, MyDto>`, if users can add any arbitrary key names they wish. With a high cardinality of dictionary keys, you run the risk of a mapping explosion and hitting the [maximum number of fields soft limit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings) and a lot of sparse fields, which can affect performance. With a `List<MyDto>` property type, you would not have this issue and can still query on the key field, at the expense of the trade-off that a `List<MyDto>` may be less optimal for your application code than a `Dictionary<string, MyDto>`. Something to consider :)

Comment: awesome explanation

Comment: Thanks for your response Russ, so if I use dynamic template, can I add normalizer to properties of MyDto? or still not possible?

Comment: and it seems in general, using a dictionary is not recommended? despite it's the closest data type to a json document?

Comment: @HosseinNassiri you can add a normalizer to the `.Keyword(k => k.Normalizer("foo"))` mapping, and anything else you need in the dynamic template mapping. A dictionary might be the nearest CLR type to a JSON document, but it is not relevant to how Elasticsearch mapping will work when given a dictionary. You can use a dictionary if you want to, but I caution that high cardinality of dictionary keys can lead to performance problems, which can be mitigated by adopting a different mapping structure. If the set of keys is known, then using a specific type is another option.