# Trouble saving IDictionary type property in ElasticSearch using NEST

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to add data to elastic search. When I'm pushing the `IDictionary<string,object>` type properties to Elasticsearch it stores the data in a different way and returns me different result.

**Model**

```
using Nest;

namespace FrontLine.Db.Elasticsearch.Models
{
    [ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "event")]
    public class Event
    {
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

        [Text(Name = "event_name")]
        public string EventName { get; set; } = null!;

        [Object]
        public IDictionary<string,object> Properties { get; set; } = null!;

    }
}
```

**Data that I'm saving**

```
[
  {
    "timeStamp": "2022-06-14T20:33:14.866Z",
    "eventName": "hello1",
    "properties": {
      "additionalProp1": "string",
      "additionalProp2": "string",
      "additionalProp3": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

**Result I'm getting from Elasticsearch**

```
[
  {
    "timeStamp": "2022-06-14T20:33:14.866Z",
    "eventName": "hello1",
    "properties": {
      "additionalProp1": {
        "valueKind": 3
      },
      "additionalProp2": {
        "valueKind": 3
      },
      "additionalProp3": {
        "valueKind": 3
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What should I change in or how should I map it to get the correct data form elastic search?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099598/how-to-map-a-property-of-type-dictionarystring-mydto-using-fluent-mapping/54100167#54100167

Comment: No it is not the possible duplicate. Thanks for commenting though.